# trigger audio .wav using php

Tags: php, wav, yammer

Need advice, guidance on triggering a .wav file to play when a web page loads content and a specific keyword is within body of that content.

The content is being pulled from a Yammer network thru a custom app I created to look for certain hashtag messages using PHP. Now, I'd like to have a sound play (like a bell) when a specific hashtag has a new message. The bell would not ring a second time, just on the intial display.

Suggestions (using PHP)?

Answer (score 0):

To play music in your site, place, `<embed src="yourfile.wav"></embed>` anywhere in page and checkout.

You can make it dynamic by using `php` in `src`.